# Icons are replaced by animating ? &?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, font-awesome-5

Setup: Asp.Net Mvc 5 + Bootstrap 3 + FontAwesome 5 Pro JS+SVG all.js (no shims)

**Code/layout.cshtml:**

```
<head>  
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <!-- Add local styles, mostly for plugins css file -->
    @if (IsSectionDefined("Styles"))
    {
        @RenderSection("Styles", required: false)
    }

    <!-- Primary Inspinia style -->
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/plugins/kendo/css")

    <!-- Section for main scripts render -->
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/kendo")
    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/js/all.js" data-auto-replace-svg="nest"></script>
    @*<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/js/all.js" ></script>*@
</head>
```

So, I'm not doing bundling because I understood that the attribute data-auto-replace-svg="nest" needs to be added. I have tried with and without the attribute. I also managed to convert all of the icons from FA4 to FA5 and am no longer using shims. I have verified my bundles as well for any possible creep of FA4.

**Usage:**

```
<nav class="navbar-default navbar-static-side" role="navigation">
    <div class="sidebar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav" id="side-menu">
            <li class="@Html.IsSelected(controller: "Dashboards")">
                <a href="@Url.Action("Primary", "Dashboards")"><i class="far fa-th-large fa-fw"></i><span class="nav-label" data-i18n="nav.dashboard">Dashboards</span> <span class="far fa-angle-down arrow"></span></a>
                <ul class="nav nav-second-level collapse @Html.IsSelected(controller: "Dashboards", cssClass: "in")">
                    <li class="@Html.IsSelected(action: "Primary")"><a href="@Url.Action("Primary", "Dashboards")"><i class="far fa-tachometer-alt fa-fw"></i>Dashboard</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li class="@Html.IsSelected(controller: "Bill")">
                <a href="@Url.Action("Search", "Bill")"><i class="far fa-archive fa-fw"></i><span class="nav-label" data-i18n="nav.bills">Bills</span><span class="far fa-angle-down arrow"></span></a>
                <ul class="nav nav-second-level collapse @Html.IsSelected(controller: "Bill", cssClass: "in")">
                    <li class="@Html.IsSelected(action: "Search")"><a href="@Url.Action("Search", "Bill")"><i class="far fa-search fa-fw"></i>Search</a></li>
                    <li class="@Html.IsSelected(action: "GenerateBillAmin")"><a href="@Url.Action("GenerateBillAmin", "Bill")"><i class="far fa-file-invoice fa-fw"></i>Receipt (Amin)</a></li>
                    <li class="@Html.IsSelected(action: "GenerateBill")"><a href="@Url.Action("GenerateBill", "Bill")"><i class="far fa-file-invoice fa-fw"></i>Receipt (Regular)</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

**Bundles/CSS:**

```
// CSS style (bootstrap/inspinia)
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                "~/Content/bootstrap.min.css",
                "~/Content/animate.min.css",
                "~/Content/style.css" ));

// CSS style (kendo)
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/plugins/kendo/css").Include(
                "~/Content/plugins/kendo/kendo.common-material.min.css",
                "~/Content/plugins/kendo/kendo.material.min.css"));
```

**Bundles/JS:**

```
// jQuery
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                "~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"));

// Bootstrap
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                "~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"));

// Kendo UI Scripts
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/kendo").Include(
                "~/Scripts/plugins/kendo/kendo.all.min.js",
                "~/Scripts/plugins/kendo/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js",
                "~/Scripts/plugins/kendo/jszip.min.js"));
```

**Final rendered icon:**

```
<li class="">
    <a href="/focus-web/Deposit/Search">
        <svg class="svg-inline--fa fa-search fa-w-16 fa-fw" aria-hidden="true" data-prefix="far" data-icon="search" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512" data-fa-i2svg="">
            <g>
                <path fill="currentColor" d="M156.5,447.7l-12.6,29.5c-18.7-9.5-35.9-21.2-51.5-34.9l22.7-22.7C127.6,430.5,141.5,440,156.5,447.7z M40.6,272H8.5 c1.4,21.2,5.4,41.7,11.7,61.1L50,321.2C45.1,305.5,41.8,289,40.6,272z M40.6,240c1.4-18.8,5.2-37,11.1-54.1l-29.5-12.6 C14.7,194.3,10,216.7,8.5,240H40.6z M64.3,156.5c7.8-14.9,17.2-28.8,28.1-41.5L69.7,92.3c-13.7,15.6-25.5,32.8-34.9,51.5 L64.3,156.5z M397,419.6c-13.9,12-29.4,22.3-46.1,30.4l11.9,29.8c20.7-9.9,39.8-22.6,56.9-37.6L397,419.6z M115,92.4 c13.9-12,29.4-22.3,46.1-30.4l-11.9-29.8c-20.7,9.9-39.8,22.6-56.8,37.6L115,92.4z M447.7,355.5c-7.8,14.9-17.2,28.8-28.1,41.5 l22.7,22.7c13.7-15.6,25.5-32.9,34.9-51.5L447.7,355.5z M471.4,272c-1.4,18.8-5.2,37-11.1,54.1l29.5,12.6 c7.5-21.1,12.2-43.5,13.6-66.8H471.4z M321.2,462c-15.7,5-32.2,8.2-49.2,9.4v32.1c21.2-1.4,41.7-5.4,61.1-11.7L321.2,462z M240,471.4c-18.8-1.4-37-5.2-54.1-11.1l-12.6,29.5c21.1,7.5,43.5,12.2,66.8,13.6V471.4z M462,190.8c5,15.7,8.2,32.2,9.4,49.2h32.1 c-1.4-21.2-5.4-41.7-11.7-61.1L462,190.8z M92.4,397c-12-13.9-22.3-29.4-30.4-46.1l-29.8,11.9c9.9,20.7,22.6,39.8,37.6,56.9 L92.4,397z M272,40.6c18.8,1.4,36.9,5.2,54.1,11.1l12.6-29.5C317.7,14.7,295.3,10,272,8.5V40.6z M190.8,50 c15.7-5,32.2-8.2,49.2-9.4V8.5c-21.2,1.4-41.7,5.4-61.1,11.7L190.8,50z M442.3,92.3L419.6,115c12,13.9,22.3,29.4,30.5,46.1 l29.8-11.9C470,128.5,457.3,109.4,442.3,92.3z M397,92.4l22.7-22.7c-15.6-13.7-32.8-25.5-51.5-34.9l-12.6,29.5 C370.4,72.1,384.4,81.5,397,92.4z"/>
                <circle fill="currentColor" cx="256" cy="364" r="26.4191">
                    <animate attributeType="XML" repeatCount="indefinite" dur="2s" attributeName="r" values="28;14;28;28;14;28;"/>
                    <animate attributeType="XML" repeatCount="indefinite" dur="2s" attributeName="opacity" values="1;0;1;1;0;1;"/>
                </circle>
                <path fill="currentColor" opacity="1" d="M263.7,312h-16c-6.6,0-12-5.4-12-12c0-71,77.4-63.9,77.4-107.8c0-20-17.8-40.2-57.4-40.2c-29.1,0-44.3,9.6-59.2,28.7 c-3.9,5-11.1,6-16.2,2.4l-13.1-9.2c-5.6-3.9-6.9-11.8-2.6-17.2c21.2-27.2,46.4-44.7,91.2-44.7c52.3,0,97.4,29.8,97.4,80.2 c0,67.6-77.4,63.5-77.4,107.8C275.7,306.6,270.3,312,263.7,312z">
                    <animate attributeType="XML" repeatCount="indefinite" dur="2s" attributeName="opacity" values="1;0;0;0;0;1;"/>
                </path>
                <path fill="currentColor" opacity="0" d="M232.5,134.5l7,168c0.3,6.4,5.6,11.5,12,11.5h9c6.4,0,11.7-5.1,12-11.5l7-168c0.3-6.8-5.2-12.5-12-12.5h-23 C237.7,122,232.2,127.7,232.5,134.5z">
                    <animate attributeType="XML" repeatCount="indefinite" dur="2s" attributeName="opacity" values="0;0;1;1;0;0;"/>
                </path>
            </g>
        </svg>
        <!-- <i class="far fa-search fa-fw"></i> -->Search</a>
</li>
```

**Rant-Repeat:**
When I switched from FA4 to FA5 with CSS+Shims, everything worked so well that I had to go with the latest JS+SVG+Shims. I did an it worked. Then I fell in love with the far icons. I found traces of all fa* (FA4) and converted them to FA5 and got rid of the shim file. I donot know what happened then. The icons never worked after that and I'm not willing to go back from JS+SVG

Answer (score 0):

I asked a similar question on GitHub for FA and immediately was told that one of the icons was from the PRO package only which made me realize I'm loading the free js file and not the custom personal Pro one. Issue resolved once I generated a new CDN link against my credentials.